# How do I parse a request parameter of type data[i][j] in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a form that posts parameters in the format data[i][j] where i is the row number and j is the column name.Now I am not sure how exactly I should retrieve these values in the controller for further processing.Is there anyway I can read these values?

Answer (score 0):

2D matrix can be represented as array of arrays or list of lists.

So post your data in the json format and parse it as list of lists

3x3 matrix can be represented like below in the json format

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Comment: I am aware of how to do it using JSON.However I am trying to figure out how to if there is any way to process form-url-encoded type array of the type mentioned above since I do not have control over the the development of the front end pages.

Comment: The way I see it can be done is by using regular expressions to pattern match values between the [ ]